# Artifact dependencies (destination) using Bamboo YAML specs

Tags: yaml, bamboo

I'm trying to set up the Bamboo build plan configuration using Bamboo YAML specs (.yml file below). In the last stage (Create deployment artifacts) I want to use the shared artifacts from the previous stage. By specifying the artifacts of the jobs as "shared: true" I can use them in the second stage. However, they are  in the same destination folder. Using the UI this can be easily edited.

[Artifact dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrRMA.png)

But how can I specify the destination folder of the two artifacts in the Bamboo YAML specs, e.g. from "Root of working directory" to "./app" and "./wwwroot", respectively?

```
---
version: 2
plan:
  project-key: COCKPIT
  key: BE
  name: Cockpit - Continuous Build - Windows 
stages:
  - Build Stage:
    - Build Backend
    - Build Frontend
  - Build Artifact:
    - Create Deployment Artifact

Build Backend:
  requirements:
    - Visual Studio Build Tools (32-bit)
  tasks:
    - checkout:
        repository: cockpit_backend
        path: 'cockpit_backend'
        force-clean-build: false
    - script:
      - dotnet publish .\cockpit_backend\src\Cockpit.WebApi\ --configuration Release

  artifacts:
    -
      name: BackendBuild
      location: cockpit_backend/src/Cockpit.WebApi/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish
      pattern: '**/*.*'
      required: true
      shared: true

Build Frontend:
  requirements:
    - os_linux
  tasks:
    - checkout:
        repository: 'Cockpit / cockpit_frontend'
        path: 'cockpit_frontend'
        force-clean-build: false
    - script:
      - cd cockpit_frontend
      - npm install
    - script:
      - cd cockpit_frontend
      - npm run build-prod
  docker: 
    image: node:alpine
  artifacts:
    -
      name: FrontendBuild
      location: cockpit_frontend/dist
      pattern: '**/*.*'
      required: true
      shared: true

Create Deployment Artifact:
  requirements:
    - os_windows
  tasks:
    - script:
        interpreter: powershell
        scripts:
          - $buildDir = "Cockpit"
          - $dest = "Cockpit_${bamboo.buildNumber}.zip"
          - Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
          - '[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($buildDir, $dest)'
  artifacts:
    -
      name: Completebuild
      pattern: 'Cockpit_${bamboo.buildNumber}.zip'
      required: true
```

Answer (score 1):

YAML specs doesn't support artifact dependency management and you need to have script task at "Create Deployment Artifact" job to put them into separate folders from root before compressing